# Replicate only some table (replicate-do-table) on Cloud SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-platform, replication, google-cloud-sql

So I have created a Cloud SQL (MySQL) DB `somedb` and its read replica `somedb-replica`, how can I replicate only some of its table (like `replicate-do-table`)?

I want to do

```
replicate-do-table=somedb.table1
replicate-do-table=somedb.table2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible, at least in the way you propose. To apply replication filters to a read replica, you would need to either pass the `--replicate-do-table=somedb.sometbl` flag when starting the replica instance, or connect to the instance later and issue the command `CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_DO_TABLE = somedb.sometbl` (available from MySQL 5.7).

1. Now, regarding the first option, this page of the [CloudSQL docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) lists all the flags with which you can start a Cloud SQL MySQL instance. So far, you can't set the `replicate-do-table` option, so the first option is unfeasible.
2. And for the second option, [you need SUPER privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-replication-filter.html). In CLoudSQL, [not even the root user has SUPER privileges](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user). So this option is unfeasible as well.